# Avoid excessive object nesting in BookshelfJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, reactjs, orm, bookshelf.js

I'm using BookshelfJS as my ORM for a RESTful ExpressJS API.  I've been using model relationships to be able to join tables that have additional details that I need for specific API calls.  Sometimes these relationships go 3 to 4 models deep and each relationship creates a new nested object.  This means that I'm creating JSON structures like this:

```
{
  "id": 45,
  "credit_check": {
    "id": 1,
    "creditor_id": 1,
    "is_complete": true,
    "creditor": {
      "id": 1,
      "business_name": "Burritotopia"
    },
  },
  "questions": [
    {
      "id": 44,
      "question_id": 2,
      "order": 1,
      "choice_response": [],
      "question": {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "Which best describes your credit status?",
        "type": "multipleChoice",
        "choices": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "question_id": 2,
            "text": "Below Average"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "question_id": 2,
            "text": "Average"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using React on the front end, and I would prefer to do any data massaging on the server. Not to mention, deeply nested objects are a pain to deal with in React.  I would really like to surface properties like `object.credit_check.creditor.business_name` to just `object.business_name` and `object.questions[0].question.text` to just `object.questions[0].text`.

Is there an easy or preferred way to achieve this type of manipulation with BookshelfJS?

Comment: Using belongsToMany() (Many-to-many relations) for your models definitions may help on this.

Comment: @DeadEye that's definitely a viable option, although when thinking through the data models these technically wouldn't have many-to-many relationships.  Not sure if that would come back to bite me later.

Comment: `questions` seems to be clearly a many-to-many relationship. You can have many questions in your "test" and a question can be in multiple tests. If it's not the case, then your database model has a problem. In this case, each question would have a "test_id" pointing directly to the test. That's the same for the creditor. If you can have multiple creditors, then this is a many-to-many relationship. If not, the creditor_id and is_complete fields should be directly in the "test" table fields